# bxslider not working with *ngFor in angular 6

Tags: angular

I am newer in angular 6 and using bxslider. its working fine with array but I am using *ngFor as dynamically its not working. How to reinitialize for dynamic data.

Working Fine with array

```
 <div class="bxslider">
     <div *ngFor="let slide of sliders"><img [src]="slide.url"></div>
</div>
```

Dynamically not working

```
 <div class="bxslider">
  <div *ngFor="let slide of banner_images"><img [src]="slide.data.image"></div>
 </div>
```

These are component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeHttpService } from 'src/app/shared/services/home/home- 
http.service';
declare var jquery:any;
declare var $ :any;
@Component({
selector: 'app-top-savers',
templateUrl: './top-savers.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./top-savers.component.css']
})
export class TopSaversComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

public banner_images: any[];

//static calling
public sliders : any[] = [
{"url":"image.jpg"},
{"url":"image.jpg"},
{"url":"image.jpg"},
{"url":"image.jpg"},
{"url":"image.jpg"}
   ];  

 constructor(private homeService:HomeHttpService) { }

 ngOnInit() {
    //fetching api data
    this.homeService.getBanner().subscribe((data) =>{   
    let banner = data[2]["objects"];
    this.banner_images = banner;
    //console.log(this.banner_images);
   });
  }

 ngAfterViewInit() {
   $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
     auto:true
   });
  }
 }
```

Please find the below image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYpig.jpg

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: I have attached the image in question but i am not getting any type of error.

Comment: have you checked browser console?

Answer (score 4):

Please change the OnInit hook to AfterViewInit.

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit} from "@angular/core";
declare var jquery:any;
declare var $ :any;
@Component({
  selector: "app-banner",
  templateUrl: './banner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./banner.component.css']
})
export class BannerComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  sliders = [
    {"url":"/images/image5.jpg"},
    {"url":"/images/image4.jpg"},
    {"url":"/images/image6.jpg"}
  ];

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    $('.slider').bxSlider({
      auto:true
    });

  }


}
```

Comment: Glad to know that, happy coding!

Comment: Hi Niral, above slider works as hard code when i use in array but same problem coming when I use dynamic data with api. slider not working. Please help me.

Comment: You need to reinitialize the slider once you have dynamic data.
Can you please add the code, how data will be passed to the component?

Comment: I updated above component code. Its not working as dynamically please help me how to reinitialize slider code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
sliders: any = []; // Declare 

<div *ngFor="let slide of sliders">
    <img [src]="slide.url" class="img-fluid">
</div>
```